# Wanted: jquery plug-in for gaming-machine-like display of numbers / high score

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, effects, animation

I'm looking for a jquery (or other javascript) plug-in that shows and animates numbers like a high-score on a gaming machine, similar to this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [monevator.com](http://monevator.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/special-dividends.png))</sub>

Is there anything like that?

Comment: that's pretty specific to be a plugin of any kind... that seems more like an application, not a framework plugin.  (P.S. I wasn't the -1)

Comment: that isn't a high score, that is a slot machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that so simply by using a transparent PNG as a foreground image to make the shadow gradient on the slot, a large background image applied to each of the slot elements with your "BAR" and "7" and such, then you could animate the css background-position property on the slot elements using jQuery.  There isn't a "slot machine" plugin out there already written that I know of, but it's painfully simple to do with whats already in the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such plugin. You can always write it yourself.